# Escaping quotation marks in PHP for JavaScript function argument

Tags: javascript, php, syntax, escaping

I'm having trouble escaping a quotation mark in PHP.
I have a table of products and each row has an onclick function, with the name of the product as the argument.

The name contains the length which is measured in inches, so the name contains a quotation mark. I wrapped an `addslashes()` around the string. This adds a backslash before the quotation mark but for some reason it doesn't seem to escape the character!

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
<?$desc1 = addslashes($row['Desc1']);?>

<tr class='tableRow' onclick='afterProductSelection("<?=$desc1?>")'>

<td><?=$row['Desc1']?></td>
```

When I inspect element in Google Chrome, the colour of the syntax indicates that this has not been escaped, clicking on it gives me a syntax error.

[image]

Probably something simple that I'm missing. Hope you can help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The `addslashes()` function is an obsolete hang-over from PHP's early days; it is not suitable for any escaping. Don't use it. Ever. For anything.    -[Spudley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/352765/spudley)

I think the function you're looking for is `htmlentities()`

```
<?=htmlentities($desc1, ENT_QUOTES)?>
```

https://www.php.net/htmlentities

Comment: Thanks! Easiest answer to implement and perfect results :)

Comment: This answer contains correct information but is incomplete. Using `addslashes()` to generate JavaScript strings is wrong and will break your page randomly.

Answer (score 4):

There are a lot of different cases where you need to escape a string. `addslashes()` is the wrong answer to pretty much all of them.

The `addslashes()` function is an obsolete hang-over from PHP's early days; it is not suitable for any escaping. Don't use it. Ever. For anything.

In your particular case, since you're creating Javascript data from PHP, use `json_encode()`.

`json_encode()` will take a PHP variable (whether it's a string, array, object or whatever) and convert it into a JSON string. A JSON string is basically fully escaped Javascript variable, including the quotes around your strings, etc. This is what you need to do.

Comment: I've +1ed for the addslashes() part, even before reading the rest :)

Answer (score 2):

You are generating a JavaScript string encoded as HTML so you need to encode twice:

- Use [json_encode()](http://php.net/json_encode) to generate the string
- Use [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) to encode as HTML

Answer (score 2):

Use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to output variables from the backend in JavaScript:

```
<tr onclick='afterProductSelection(<? print json_encode($desc1); ?>)'>
```

**N.B.:** For string output there is no need for extra quotes.